# Lua: How do I print a multiline string/variable?

Tags: string, lua, multiline

So I'm asking this question as I have completely no idea on how to code in Lua. My goal is to print a multiline string that prints a string with line breaks in them. This is so I can modify a Rainmeter skin so that I can show a list of text. I've tried using double square brackets, \n instead of a line break and of course, a traditional line break doesn't work. This is how the code looks like at the moment:

```
NoArtistNameText=title
NoTrackNameText=[[item 1
item 2
item 3
item 4
item 5]]
```

(btw this is from the Monstercat Visualizer by MarcoPixel).

Comment: *(this is from the Monstercat Visualizer by MarcoPixel but I edited the variables from 'N/A' to my own ones)

Comment: the current code above just shows the first line (as a normal variable would)

Comment: `print` works..

Comment: afaik, i can't use `print` on this. if you want, i can send you the full .ini file

Comment: It is unclear what are you asking. StackOverflow is not a mailing list to send broken files to people. SO is not an idea site that gives ideas how to code. SO is a site where you provide minimal complete example of a problem encountered in a code you wrote, and people explain what is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be tagged as Lua, for one, as it's just Rainmeter dot ini modification.

The function you're looking for as far as I can tell from the question you've posed is found at [the documentation for Rainmeter](https://docs.rainmeter.net/manual/variables/built-in-variables/). Scroll down, it's called `#CRLF#`.

Documentation is outlined as follows:

> `#CRLF#`
>   Creates a `\n` newline control character where used. Useful in String meters to display text on separate lines.
>
> Example: `Text=Line1#CRLF#Line2`
>
> Note: The Windows standard `\r\n` (carriage return / linefeed) is not needed in String meters in Rainmeter, but it you wanted to obtain that, perhaps to write to some file, you would use the Character Reference Variables syntax of [\13][\10], which would be resolved to \r\n, or carriage return / linefeed.

Your implementation would be something like this:

```
NoArtistNameText=title
NoTrackNameText=item 1 #CRLF# item 2 #CRLF# item 3 #CRLF# item 4 #CRLF# item 5
```